# mapping characters from dict to a list of words

Tags: python

I have a char dict and i want to replace every instance of a key i encounter in some word with its value.

My dict looks like this:

```
 map_to_num = {
        "w": "1",
        "x": "2",
        "z": "3" }
```

And a list of words:

```
lst = ["water","xavier"]
```

I've tried using the `map()` function, but it keeps returning `None`:

```
nw = list(map(map_to_num.get, lst))
```

Comment: lst is a list of strings

Comment: When you do `map(map_to_num.get, lst)`, it ends up running `map_to_num.get("water")`, and since `map_to_num` has no attribute `"water"` it doesn't work as expected

Comment: are the keys/values always one character?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be applying the `map_to_num` to each string in  `lst` separately. Also you need to provide a default value for your `dict.get` to keep characters that are not in `map_to_num`:

```
>>> nw = ["".join(map_to_num.get(c, c) for c in word) for word in lst]
>>> nw
['1ater', '2avier']
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you where here we can achieve our goal with simple indexing and string concatenation:

```
>>> lst = ['water','xavier']
>>> list(map(lambda x: map_to_num.get(x[0])+x[1:],lst))
['1ater', '2avier']
```